# In an OfficeJS add-in, will updating the MinVersion requirement set affect existing installs?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

It's clear that new users won't be able to install the add-in, but are existing users affected after a manifest MinVersion update? Will they no longer be able to load (or even see?) the add-in?

Comment: This actually depends on the Exchange version as well as the client version. And I assume that your addin is in the addin store. Yes, if the user is on Exchange online, and the user is on an older client (Outlook 2016), MinVersion min version is updated to one that is no longer supported by the client, Exchange picks up the updated manifest and user will no longer sees the addin. This option is for addins that no longer want to run in older clients. You also do not have to change MinVersion. Could you tell us a bit more on your scenario or what you want to achieve?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks for your response. I am looking to prevent new users from installing the add-in if they are on a version earlier than Outlook 2021 or an Office 365 sub. I'd like existing users to stay unaffected in the process. My idea was to use the [requirement sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) to enforce this in the MinVersion. In this case, I was thinking I'd update the MinVersion to 1.9, preventing new users, but existing users earlier than 1.9 can still access the add-in (while installed).

Comment: If you update the requirement set to 1.9, existing users that do not support 1.9 will no longer be able to access the add-in. Additionally, support for 1.9 in Outlook on Windows with a Microsoft 365 subscription is available from version 2008 (build 13127.20296), so those new users would have access to the add-in.